# Erro na função em python3

Tags: python-3.x, funções

Fiz essa função onde será atribuído um nome e um valor, que entram em um laço while repetindo 5 vezes, a cada vez que o laço se repetir os valores vão ser atribuídos a uma lista diferente, por fim ele calcula a média dos valores de cada lista e a retorna, porem está dando um erro e não estou conseguindo resolver.

> ERRO:line 20, in media_ms
>       media = (dic0[nome] + dic1[nome] + dic2[nome] + dic3[nome] + dic4[nome]) / 5 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dic4' referenced
>   before assignment.

```
def media_ms(site_nome, site_ms):
    nome = str(site_nome)
    ms = float(site_ms)
    y = 0
    while y < 4:
        if y == 0:
            dic0 = {nome: ms}
        elif y == 1:
            dic1 = {nome: ms}
        elif y == 2:
            dic2 = {nome: ms}
        elif y == 3:
            dic3 = {nome: ms}
        elif y == 4:
            dic4 = {nome: ms}

        y += 1

    if y==4:
        media = (dic0[nome] + dic1[nome] + dic2[nome] + dic3[nome] + dic4[nome]) / 5

    return media

t = media_ms('google.com', 40)
print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu código nunca entra no

```
elif y == 4:
```

, pois seu *while* é **<4** e nao **<=4**...

Dessa maneira, ele não cria seu ***dic4***, por isso o erro " local variable 'dic4' referenced before assignmen".

Ajuste seu *while* ou então instancie sua variavel **dic4** como vazio no começo do código: ***dic4 = {}***

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

```
def media_ms(site_nome, site_ms):
    nome = str(site_nome)
    ms = float(site_ms)
    y = 0
    while y <= 4:
        if y == 0:
            dic0 = {nome: ms}
        elif y == 1:
            dic1 = {nome: ms}
        elif y == 2:
            dic2 = {nome: ms}
        elif y == 3:
            dic3 = {nome: ms}
        elif y == 4:
            dic4 = {nome: ms}
        y += 1

    if y == 5:
        media = (dic0[nome] + dic1[nome] + dic2[nome] + dic3[nome] + dic4[nome]) / 5

    return media

t = media_ms('google.com', '40')
print(t)
```

Ai esta seu código funcionando, o que alterei foi:

no while, para que o loop chegasse até o final, alterei o comparador 'y < 4' por 'y <= 4'

e troquei o valor do if final de 4 para 5.

O seu erro estava acontecendo porque o if final não estava sendo acessado, e voce retornava uma variavel que não havia sido instanciada.

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer duvida pode me informar